# Execute async function but i need to await for access_token to continue with other task

Tags: node.js

I just want to execute async functions in nodejs to response first but later execute a task in background:

look at the code

but every time I receive a 401 from function executeCreateNewPizza (both are http request), thats told me that createNewPizza is not awaiting for the first to get the access_token and thats why I think fails, did you know how I should to handle de async functions?, thanks

i try this one in my controller:

```js
const receiveOrder = async (req, resp) => {
    resp.json({message: 'ok, We will create your Pizza soon, thanks!'})
    setTimeout(()=>{
        var access_token = executeRequireAccessTokken() // implements: 
 return new Promise...
        var createNewPizza = executeCreateNewPizza(access_token, 
 req.body) // implements: return new Promise...
        ...
    }, 5000)
}
```